Error: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN WordPress / Woocommerce
I manage a website created in WordPress with the Woocommerce Plugin. Everything was going well until one day I noticed that some products show an error when viewing them. It practically shows the product and within milliseconds the error appears: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. I will attach a screenshot.
This error doesn't only appear on my computer, but on all devices, and I really don't know what to do to fix it. I have already searched in different videos, but they seem to explain it as if the issue was with my browser, when in reality it happens on any device. Additionally, this only happens with some products, not all of them.
The same thing happens when I create a new product in Woocommerce.
Could someone please help me! 
Error example link: https://amanecermedico.com/producto/silla-de-ruedas-estandar/


Some quick searching suggests this is a network problem. You might have more luck finding an answer on Stack Overflow. When you say it's on "all devices", are they all on the same network? Do you have the problem, say, on a phone connected to 5G instead of your home router? You will probably have to contact your ISP for assistance with this. For what it's worth, your example link loads just fine in my browser, which is, of course, on a completely different network.

Causes:
The browser can't find the website because the domain isn't registered or may be expired.
The domain does not point to any IP address.
The DNS settings on the user's computer are incorrect, so it can't find the domain.
how to Fixes:

Flush the DNS
Open the Command prompt and run the code:
ipconfig /flushdns
This will solve the error.

Modify DNS server
Open the Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center.
On the left side of the window, choose Change adapter settings.
Right-click on your current connection & click on Properties
Select TCP/IPv4 or TCP/IPv6 and press the Properties button.
Use the below DNS server addresses and add the  below numbers:


Preferred DNS Server.
8.8.8.8 (IPv4)
2001:4860:4860::8888 (IPv6)
Alternate DNS Server.
8.8.4.4 (IPv4)
2001:4860:4860::8844 (IPv6)
Restart your browser & check whether the issue is solved or not.

Restart the DNS Client Service
Press the Windows + R and type msconfig.
Open the Services tab and find the DNS Client option.
Uncheck to turn it off and click OK.
Restart the computer.
Repeat steps 1 and 2. Erecheck the box to activate the DNS Client.
Restart again to check if the error has been fixed.

Deactivate Antivirus or VPN
Go to the Settings > Network & Internet > VPN.
Choose the VPN service that you are using and click Disconnect.
Restart the computer and then open the site to check if the problem has disappeared.

Point your domain to your IP address
You have to update your domain's DNS settings. Follow the below steps:

Specify Your IP Address: Ensure you have the IP address of your server that you wish the domain to point to.

Access Your Domain Registrar's DNS Settings: Log in to the account where your domain is registered.

Find the DNS Management Area: Look for an option related to DNS management. This should be labelled as "DNS Settings," "DNS Management," "Manage DNS," or something like that.

Modify Your A Record: The A record in your DNS settings points your domain to an IP address.
  
Locate the A Record: Search the existing A record for your domain. If it does not exist, you will need to add one.


Edit the A Record:
Host: Enter the hostname. For the root domain (e.g., test.com), use @. For a subdomain (e.g., test.com), you use www.
Points to: Add your server's IP address.
TTL: Set the TTL (Time to Live), usually in seconds. Standard defaults are 3600 seconds (1 hour).
Example:
Host: @
Points to: 192.0.2.2 (your server's IP address)
TTL: 3600
Save Changes
Save or apply the changes. It may take time for the changes to propagate through the internet, generally anywhere from a few minutes to 48 hours.
Verify the Change
To check if your domain is indicating the correct IP address, you can use tools like:
DNS Checker
nslookup command in your command line or terminal:  nslookup yourdomain.com
Check Subdomains: If you have subdomains, you may need to make additional A records for each subdomain.
Using CNAME Records: You can also use CNAME records pointing to the root domain for subdomains.
SSL Certificates: If your website uses HTTPS, make sure your SSL certificate is correctly configured for the new IP address.

That doesn't look like the case from the question though. it looks like the site is trying to use some description text as an URL when it isn't.
